# Discrepancy in the widths of programmatically added views vs. interface builder views

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uikit

I have come across a conundrum of sorts in regards unexpected (at least for me) sizes of `UIView`s.

Consider this `UIViewController` class. `interfaceBuilderView` was declared in a `Storyboard` file and constrained to take up the whole area of the `UIView`. So, I would expect to have `interfaceBuilderView` be the same size as `programicallyCreatedView` when calling `*.frame.width`. But they aren't.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var interfaceBuilderView: MyCustomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let programmicallyCreatedView = MyCustomView(frame: self.view.frame)

        //commented out this to get first picture
        self.view.addSubview(programmicallyCreatedView)

        self.interfaceBuilderView.setAppearance()
        self.programmicallyCreatedView.setAppearance()

        print(self.view.frame.width)//prints 375
        print(self.interfaceBuilderView.frame.width)//prints 600
        print(self.programmicallyCreatedView.frame.width)//prints 375
    }

}
```

Now, consider this implementation of the `MyCustomView` class.

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomView: UIView {

    func setAppearance() {

        let testViewWidth: CGFloat = 200.0
        let centerXCoor = (self.frame.width - testViewWidth) / 2.0

        let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(centerXCoor, 0, testViewWidth, 100))
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.addSubview(testView)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I simply draw a red rectagle of width 200.0, and it is supposed to be centered. Here are the results.

Using the Interface Builder created view.

[image]

---

And using the programmatically created view.

[image]

---

As you can see, the programmatically created view achieves the desired results. No doubt because the size printed is the same as the superview (375).

Therefore, my question is simply why is this happening? Furthermore, how can I use a view declared in interface builder and programmatically add other views to it with dimensions and placement that I expect?

Comment: Views created in the interface builder start with whatever their dimensions are in the interface builder (the default height/width is the 600 you see in your log) and then update when the view lays out its subviews at some point before it comes on screen.  You're programatically adding a view that is centered in the 600 width view but isn't set up to resize itself when it's superview changes size.  Add constraints to keep the view centered in its superview and they will both look the same.

Comment: @dan, pretty sure that what you are talking about doesn't work. I added centering horizontally and vertically and it all was the same.

Comment: In your code you aren't adding any constraints to the red view

Comment: @dan, sorry for not understanding... Thanks, that helps me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. This code is accessing `frame` values in `viewDidLoad`, but the `frame` values are not yet reliable at that point. The view hasn't been laid out yet. If you're going to mess around with custom `frame` values, do this in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
2. Nowadays, we really don't generally use `frame` values anymore. Instead, we define constraints to define the layout programmatically. Unlike custom `frame` values, you can define constraints when you add the subviews in `viewDidLoad`.
3. You have the scene's main `view`, the `MyCustomView` and then yet another `UIView` which is red. That strikes me as unnecessarily confusing.

I would advise that you just add your programmatically created subview in `viewDidLoad` and specify its constraints. Using the new iOS 9 constraints syntax, you can just specify that it should be centered, adjacent to the top of the `view`, half the width, and one quarter the height:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let redView = UIView()
    redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(redView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        redView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor),
        redView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor),
        redView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
        redView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25)
    ])
}
```

Clearly, adjust these constraints as suits you, but hopefully this illustrates the idea. Don't use `frame` anymore, but rather use constraints.